# Difference between local values and production values

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel

I'm using Laravel to get some data from my DB. Here is my code:

```
$payments =  DB::table('pm7_payments7')
                        ->where('id', 'ce86bb2f-5e01-d289-3a89-55dfb5109de6')
                        ->get();
```

Locally I get this:

[image]

On my production server, I get this:

[image]

As you can see, locally the "total_amount" field is 825.00 (correct), but on the production server it's "820.0" (incorrect).

Do you know what could make this difference between the two servers?

Comment: Perhaps you, or someone else, populated the tables in a different way? :)

Comment: No the table is exactly the same. The data should be the same, since locally, I'm connecting to the production database server.

So same mysql, same data, same laravel version, only the PHP version is different.

Comment: What happens if you make that query on the shell?

Comment: It's working fine. So it's a code related issue. But the code is exactly the same. So I guess Laravel doesn't work the same way with different PHP versions :(

Comment: Well, then my guess would be for you to update the PHP to the same version and run some tests.

Comment: What's the total amount in the database?

Comment: @MihkelAllorg in the database the total_amount is a float(18,2), and its value is 825.00

Comment: @Mauker, unfortunately I can't upgrade PHP on my server :(